# Making workflow in 2 different list for number of pieces of products

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

i'm kinda new in sharepoint so i started to doing some project. I have 2 list.
In list 1 i have: 
Product,
Price,
Number of products.
In second list i have:
Customer,
to chose a product, and 
Number of product that he can enter and buy from me.
My problem is now, how can i do it in workflow when customer enter number of product that the number of product from list 1 change as well. 
So if I have in List one number of product 20, and customer come and buy 10, how to make that automatically updates list 1. Thnak you

Comment: Do you want the  Product Number value in List 1 to be equal to the Product Number value in List 2? Or do you want the value in List 2 to change the value in List 1 (eg - Number of Product in List 1 is 20 and when Number of Product in List 2 is 10, this updated the value in List 1 to be 10 because 20-10=10)?

Comment: I want to value in list 2 to change valie in list 1, Thank you